# Import Unity 2D objects in Libgdx

Tags: unity, libgdx

I'm using Libgdx to do some simple home projects. I'm trying to make a simple 2D game with Box2d using R.U.B.E as editor. I create a 2d terrain in R.U.B.E now I want to create the terrain texture. 
I see this tool for Unity:

https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/15761

This type of tool is exactly what I need for terrains. What I want to know is not related with this specific tool, but I wan't to know if I can import Unity 2d objects generated by tools related to Unity in my Libgdx 2d games?